# Один файл js не видит действия другого

Tags: javascript, html

Есть два файла *.js , в первом создание дива.
Во втором пытаюсь привязать к этому событие `onclick`, но выводит `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`. Сделать все в одном файле не получится.
Первый файл успел исполниться , так-как в html этот див отобразился.
Код первого файла:
`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "<div id = 'class'></div>"`
Код второго файла:
`document.getElementById("class").onclick = function(event){}`
Скрипты без `async/defer`

Comment: Кол второго файла? Первый точно успел исполнится?

Comment: Да вполне, ведь див отобразился в html.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук событие как вешаете? Покажите код обоих файлов

Comment: Ни в коем случае не показывайте нам код файлов. Мы будем гадать, пока не угадаем.

Comment: Вы что, печатаете код в вопрос? `getElementByid`?

Comment: Тэги `script` с этими файлами - секретные?

Comment: @Igor чисто html и 2 js

Comment: Что это значит? Кому из нас нужна помощь?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Из-за `window.onload` первый файл, который должен создавать поле, выполнялся после загрузки всего документа. А так-как второй файл выполнялся сразу как только браузер его находил то он не мог прицепить событие `onclick` к полю, которое на этот момент еще не создано первым файлом.

Comment: То есть с кодами файлов в тексте вопроса вы нам наврали и там всё-таки не весь код, понятно) И именно поэтому не смогли получить помощи от нас.

Comment: @andreymal Я думал window.onload не имеет значения.

Comment: В этом и заключалась Ваша ошибка. Не надо думать. Надо честно показывать код. "Минус ставлю Вам." (с)

Answer (score 0):

Не нужны мне никакие тэги.

> "Я все вспомнил. Это ардабиола." Е.Евтушенко

В Ваших тэгах есть атрибуты `async`/`defer`, или Вы создаете их в коде. В этом случае порядок загрузки скриптов не гарантирован.

Comment: Допустим, это не ответ как решить проблему

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук Что значит "допустим"? Какую проблему? Я Вам сказал, в чем дело. Хватит темнить.

Comment: Скажите как решить проблему , а не в чём она заключена.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук покажите скрипты - скажем как решить, пока только в чем она =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я и подожду

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук чего? пришествия телепатов которые ваши скрипты из вашей головы считают и найдут проблему?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков там написан весь код

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук Ну тогда поместите код последовательно друг за другом и проблема исчерпана. #ждите_телепатов

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук Телепат здесь! Вы ждали и я пришел! Давайте я почитаю что у вас там... Хмм... Думайте о коде, думайте. Да что вы все о девочках думаете!